# Is it possible in php to take a sqlite database and mysql database and run queries against each other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

The two databases are identical and I send the sqlite to my server and I was wondering if it's possible to check if rows in one of the sqlite tables are not in the mysql equivalent table. I then want to add those rows to the mysql database. Is there a easy way to do this in php or do I have to extract the results from the sqlite table and build queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to do, but not in one query, you will need one query on one database, another query on the other database, and have PHP compare the two.

Comment: Ok can it compare like a sql compare where it returns all the values not in compare?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, SQL doesn't "compare" it checks the value of fields, you tell it which. In PHP you can do the same, compare rows for certain fields and see if they match.